# Triple boot on Mac Mini 1,1 - primary partitions, rEFIt

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, refit

I have a Mac Mini 1,1 (Core Duo / 32-bit, from 2006) with rEFIt installed. I've been running a dual boot configuration like the following successfully for quite a while now:

- Mac OS X
- Lubuntu 15.04

Now I have updated the RAM to 2 GB and replaced the hard drive by a larger SSD. I want to add to the above a third OS:

- Windows 10 (Pro)

I have thus created a bootable USB stick using the official ISO of Windows 10 32-bit, which shows up in rEFIt three times (each with the USB decoration, but only the rightmost menu item actually works), and I also still see Mac OS X and Ubuntu (with the hard drive icon).

When I proceed in order to do a fresh install of Windows 10 in the unassigned free space on the SSD, at some point I get the message `Windows can't be installed on this drive since the maximum number of partitions of this type is reached`.

I guess "this type" refers to primary partitions, and it seems I already have four of them:

There are four primary partitions, among them probably the extended partition containing Linux. I then deleted the GRUB partition during Windows Setup (since I was sure I could easily recreate this one later), and managed to install Windows, which finally appeared in the rEFIt boot menu as "legacy OS", but Ubuntu was lost.

I learned that by deleting the GRUB partition I lost the opportunity to boot Linux. So I re-created / reinstalled grub with my original Lubuntu CD, then Windows was lost.

And this time, more severely lost, because the partitions now show up again just as in the beginning. Instead of an NTFS partition, there is *unassigned free space* (again). I remember that when I started GParted, it asked if it shall correct some error, which I approved. Was that a bad idea?

I'm puzzled that an entire partition seems to be erased like that. Running Windows repair setup, I don't see any NTFS partition either.

Can't I have a triple boot setup of Mac OS X / Lubuntu 15.04 / Windows 10, and if so, exactly how do I need to proceed?

Comment: +1 for being adventurous. You can of course triple boot, but I think gparted did something while correcting errors

Comment: Thank you. I wonder how to overcome that mythical four-primary-partition limit. With rEFIt / GRUB, I'm not even sure which partition(s) actually need to be primary ones. Naïvely, I would guess that in order to be able to choose to boot between three systems, it should not be necessary to have more than three (or four, fwiw) primary partitions .. certainly I have to understand what role the different part(ition)s play.

Comment: Hint: You can create 3 primary partitions and make the rest extended partitions. and in that partition you can create as much partition as you need. This is for MBR partition scheme

Comment: I've answered a similar question from you [on superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/1111996/exact-how-to-for-refit-mac-mini-32-bit-os-x-ubuntu-win-10). You ***MUST*** understand hybrid MBRs and the difference between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting before you venture into these waters, or you'll find yourself drowning pretty quickly.